# Is there a way in python/java/scala to convert/normalize log normal distribution into normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, normalization, lognormal-distribution

We have a data set that looks like a lognormal distribution when we plot it.

We would like to convert/normalize the distribution into normal distribution and see what feature weight got enhanced.

It there a way to do it in python/java/scala?

Answer (score 1):

Take the log of each point in the dataset. You could do this in any language.